# Split text into 4 characters with no delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, split, substring

Any idea on how I can split a long string of text into multiple records with a fixed width of 4 characters each and with no delimiter?

For example:

Source:

```
1   11223344
2   ABCD
3   XYZ12345
```

Expected result:

```
1 1122
1 3344
2 ABCD
3 XYZ1
3 2345
```

The long string of text is currently in one column of a table. My end results is to put the first 4 char of it into one record, the next 4 char into the other record and so on and so forth. i also need to have an identifier to tell that the first X number of records belong to the first record of the source file etc (in the above example, it is the first column - 1, 2, 3)

Comment: is the `a long string of text into multiple records` in one field of a table? or multiple fields, tables?

Comment: the long string of text is currently in one column of a table. my end results is to put the first 4 char of it into one record, the next 4 char into the other record and so on and so forth. i also need to have an identifier to tell that the first X number of records belong to the first record of the source file etc (in the above example, it is the first column - 1,2,3).

Comment: you don't have a delimiter in your `source ?` i think if you source is like that `1   11223344` the delimiter is the `Tab`

Comment: the first 1 then you see is just another column, the id field. the text field that needs to be split, unfortunately, has no delimiter. the rule to split is just by width, 4 characters each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps.

1. Create a function for split your data by character length .

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION SplitStringByLength
   (   
    @inputString varchar(max),
    @length int
   )
   RETURNS @SplitStrings TABLE( SplitString VARCHAR(50) ) 
   AS
   BEGIN
     DECLARE @s VARCHAR(50)
     WHILE len(@inputString) > 0
      BEGIN
         SET @s = left(@inputString, @length)
         SET @inputString = right(@inputString, len(@inputString) - @length)
         INSERT @SplitStrings VALUES (@s)
      END
   RETURN 
   END
   ```
2. call the function by passing your column and length of characters as input like below.

   ```
   SELECT ID ,SplitString
   FROM YourTable
     CROSS APPLY 
     dbo.SplitStringByLength (YourColumn,4)-- mention the character length to split
   ```

**Output :** 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this queries for desired output:

```
Select substring('11223344',0,5)
Select substring('11223344',5,9)
Select substring('ABCD',0,5)
------Select substring('ABCD',5,9)
Select substring('XYZ12345',0,5)
Select substring('XYZ12345',5,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive CTE can help you:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  ID,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(string,1,4) as nvarchar(4))as S,
        LEN(String) as L,
        1 as [Level]
FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT  y.ID,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(string,(4*[Level])+1,(4*[Level])+4) as nvarchar(4)),
        L-4,
        [Level]+1
FROM YourTable y
INNER JOIN cte c
    ON y.ID = c.ID 
WHERE L > 4
)

SELECT  ID,
        S
FROM cte
ORDER BY ID
```

Output:

```
ID  S
1   1122
1   3344
2   ABCD
3   XYZ1
3   2345
```